# parse() в ViArt

Tags: php, cms

Доброго времени суток. Работаю в не слишком известной в русскоязычных кругах cms ViArt. Весь вывод в ней осуществляется посредством функций **parse()**, **global_parse()** etcetera, но в то же время я не смог найти места их задания по "function parse" например. Поясните, откуда берутся эти ф-ии?

Comment: плохо искал. благодарю

Answer (score 0, accepted):

функция (если это функция, а не метод класса) должна быть задана. Ищите в исходниках лучше. возможно там написано:

```
function
parse(...
или 
function  parse(...
```

Попробуйте поискать регулярным выражением:

```
function[\s\r\n]+parse
```